# How to set startup Root Route with # in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am developing SPA with Angular and want to set startup route like this

```
http://cc-ng-z.azurewebsites.net
```

If you go to above url, it automatically append `/#/` at the end, so it select the route from the one which define in routing configuration. Please let me know how it is possible?

Update:

```
var app = angular.module('app');

    //collect the routes
    app.constant('routes', getRoutes());

    app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);

        function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes) {

            routes.forEach(function (r) {

                $routeProvider.when(r.url, r.config);
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }



    function getRoutes() {
            return [
                {
                    url: '/',
                    config: {
                        title: 'dashboard',
                        templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                        settings: {
                            nav: 1,
                            content: '<i class="icon-home"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Dashboard</span>'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    url: '/projects',
                    config: {
                        title: 'projects',
                        templateUrl: '/app/project/project.html',
                        settings: {
                            nav: 2,
                            content: '<i class="icon-th"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Projects</span>'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    url: '/project/new',
                    config: {
                        title: 'project',
                        templateUrl: '/app/project/newProject.html',
                        settings: {}
                    }
                }
            ];
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is the default behavior. As long as you have your routes set up on your index page, it will append /#/ to the end of it.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             templateUrl: 'home-template',
             controller: 'AppController'
        })
});
```

Inside the settings for /, you can also pass in a key 'redirectTo' if you want to redirect to another client-side route.

Comment: Please check the updated question, I added my code for routing but it's not appending /#/ at the end, please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: You aren't calling getRoutes, or you didn't paste that here. Can you post a JSBin?

Comment: Missed that statement. Added Now

Comment: Actually I am not using index.html instead I have a Razor view. After use successfully logged in, SPA suppose to be loaded.

Comment: did you do this: var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

Comment: Yes, I already resolved all the dependencies. In fact other routes work fine including / route..But I want to have my url look like this http://www.example.com/#/ instead of http://www.example.com...So It will select the default route.

Comment: the following gist works. i tried it on a demo app on my computer - https://gist.github.com/skaterdav85/42aaf45fa143d52a617b